# Binding a series of commands to a key

Tags: key-bindings

After a few trials and errors, I finally managed to find a series of customization for my Emacs to be the almost perfect distraction free environment. However, I don't want these settings to load every time I open Emacs, I want to be able to press a button (like <kbd>F10</kbd>) and have a chain of commands executed, like the following:

```
M-x load-theme solarized-dark
M-x org-mode
M-x olivetti-mode
M-x olivetti-set-width 120
M-x wc-goal-count
```

And I would like to revert the commands and their effect, once I'm done with writing (obviously without quitting Emacs).

An acceptable course of action (maybe more elegant) would be to execute all this when loading *olivetti-mode*, since I'll use this mode exclusively in distraction free environment, but I would like to be able to revert all those settings too. I'm sure it's possible, but I can't figure it out yet.

I'm obviously a n00b, so any idea, setting, hint, link that would simplify my workflow is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new function and bind it to a key:

```el
(defun no-distraction ()
   "Switch to no distraction env"
   (interactive)
   (load-theme 'tango)
   (org-mode)
   (olivetti-mode)
   (olivetti-set-width 120)
   (wc-goal-count))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'no-distraction)
```

Save this into your `.emacs` file.

Semi-tested only (I don't have olivetti-mode installed). Might need further tweaking.

Comment: I haven't inspected the five (5) functions at issue, but sometimes functions test for whether they are interactively called, and it may be necessary to use `call-interactively` or else the function might behave differently than expected.  The original poster is also requesting an *undo* / *restore* function -- i.e., go there with one function, and put everything back the way it was with another function.

Comment: @Drew: It's on the first line.

Comment: @choroba: It works as intended, it executes a series of commands and it seems to do it properly. It doesn't have the *undo/restore* command, but I don't mine. Thank you!