# If text is copied from pdf on yank run unfill-paragraph

Tags: org-mode, pdf

It's similar problem [Copy and Paste From PDF to Emacs as Plain Text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21656/copy-and-paste-from-pdf-to-emacs-as-plain-text) When I copy text from pdf and yank to org mode I have to run manually `unfill-paragraph` function to remove unnecessary newlines & spaces. How I can automate the process?

I think condition would look like this -> If text is copied from pdf on yank run `unfill-paragraph`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding a series of commands to a key](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32348/binding-a-series-of-commands-to-a-key)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of another question. The other question is about different commands, but the solution applies here just as well: create a new function that includes both of the commands you want to run (yank and unfill-paragraph), and bind that function to a new keybinding.

Comment: But I need to apply this functionality only to text copied from pdf. A that's makes a difference.

Comment: I don’t believe it is possible for Emacs to determine where some text originated. Your best bet would be a custom key binding for your own “paste and reformat” command.

Comment: Ok, that's more involved. I think you can do this by applying a text property to the text as you copy it from the pdf, and setting up a yank-handler to check for that property and call fill-paragraph when you paste it. I'll need some time to look into that; maybe someone else can answer faster!